# What datatype is used to insert only 'YEAR' in Informix?

Tags: informix

I am trying to create a table in that one column should accept only 'YEAR'
eg: 2017, 2018, 2019 along with 'CURRENT YEAR' as default value.

I am unable to create such a column — can you please help me?

Expected Output :

```
 ID      Today_Year
-----    -----------
100       2017
101       2018
102       2018
```

The database server is Informix.

Comment: A year is just `integer`

Answer (score 1):

You could do that as follows:

```
create table t2 (c1 datetime year to year default current year to year, c2 int);

insert into t2 (c2) values(100);
insert into t2 values ('2017',101);
insert into t2 values (current,102);
select * from t2;


c1            c2

2018         100
2017         101
2018         102
```

Comment: I am getting result like this   c1                    c2
 --------------------- ---
 2018-03-01 00:00:00.0 100
 2017-03-01 00:00:00.0 101
 2018-03-01 00:00:00.0 102 . i used your query only

Comment: @Shangeetha: you must have mistyped something, or gotten inventive in the SELECT statement.  The type `DATETIME YEAR TO YEAR` cannot return month, day or time columns on its own — at least, not with a front-end tool that understands Informix.  I suppose that some of the interfaces might do funny type mappings.  What tool did you use to generate the output you see?

Comment: We are using Informix Data Studio. 12.1. Do i need to set anything in server level for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of a number of types.  The 'obvious' one is:

- DATETIME YEAR TO YEAR

The least obvious one is:

- INTERVAL YEAR TO YEAR — not recommended

The other alternative is simply an integer type:

- SMALLINT
- INTEGER
- BIGINT — overkill; not recommended
- INT8 — deprecated; do not use

The integer types may be easier to use in the long run than DATETIME YEAR TO YEAR; I'd almost certainly use INTEGER or SMALLINT.

---

> How can I create a table with a 'year' column and the default value in that column is the current year?

Hmmm; that's hard to do with an INTEGER type.  At that point, DATETIME comes to the rescue:

```
CREATE TABLE YearTable
(
    RowNumber   SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    YearColumn  DATETIME YEAR TO YEAR NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT YEAR TO YEAR,
    DateColumn  DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT TODAY
);

INSERT INTO YearTable(RowNumber) VALUES(0);
SELECT * FROM YearTable;
```

That yields, for example (assuming `DBDATE=Y4MD-` in the environment):

```
1       2018    2018-03-05
```

You can't use arbitrary expressions for defaults even when they seem reasonable — which is irksome.  Hence, if you need the default, the DATETIME YEAR TO YEAR type is the type of choice.  (That's what [jrenaut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9434429/jrenaut) suggested in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49070906/15168).)

You could arrange for a trigger with an integer type; that is considerably harder work, though.

Comment: How to set a current year as a default value if we use integer or smallint?

Comment: I've added a section to the question — and essentially changed the recommendation from 'an integer type' to 'DATETIME YEAR TO YEAR'.

Comment: Thank You. i will try this.